# Best way to find a expression in esprima

Tags: esprima

I need to check a code and find if there's the use of timer expressions in a esprima tree. Do you know the best way to do this? thanks

Comment: Take a look at [estraverse](https://github.com/estools/estraverse) to easily walk over all nodes of an AST tree

Comment: @MichaelRadinov looks really interesting, thanks!